# dynamodb - boto3 client works resource throws error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

When I use the client to get_item from a table using Key it works fine. If I try the same with Resource I get error. Whats going wrong here

```
>>> ddbr = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
>>> table = ddbr.Table('employees')
>>> table.get_item(Key={'EmpId': {'S': '13456789ABC'}})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/qwert/miniconda2/envs/pyenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/qwert/miniconda2/envs/pyenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/Users/qwert/miniconda2/envs/pyenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 312, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/qwert/miniconda2/envs/pyenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 601, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to declare the type in dynamo Json format; boto does that for you. If your table’s partition key is named ‘EmpId’ and is of type string your  get item call should look like

`table.get_item(Key={'EmpId':'13456789ABC'})`

Answer (score 1):

Boto3 provides two service abstractions:

1. Client (low-level)
2. Resource (high-level, object-oriented abstraction on top of Client)

And there are two corresponding DynamoDB get_item methods:

1. [DynamoDB Client](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#client) has a [get_item()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.get_item) method
2. [DynamoDB Table](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#table) (a Resource) has a [get_item()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.get_item) method

If you read the documentation for each method you will see that they expect the item key to be provided in two different ways (in my example I'm assuming it's a string):

1. Client: Key = { "column" : { "S" : "value" } }
2. Resource: Key = { "column" : "value" }

There's a good [Introduction to Version 3 of the AWS SDK for Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cb2czfCV4Dg) video.